# centerVertical not working in a layout

Tags: android

[here are the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF1wU.png)
Here when i am using layout_centerHorizontal its working perfectly but whenever i use layout_centerVertical its not working.How can i solve this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4081">

    <TextView
        android:text="Have a nice day"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your screenshots for both cases

Comment: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` will work. What exactly your query is?

Comment: i want to align my text vertically center to the left or right side of the parent ,i am using [android_visualizer](https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer) for practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this, it works on Android studio, the textview will be centered vertically on the parent's right side :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4081">

    <TextView
        android:text="Have a nice day"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```